# Do Javascript prototypes have something equivalent to Lua's __index & __newindex?

Tags: javascript, prototype, lua

I want to define a behavior on Javascript objects that kicks in when the referenced attribute/method doesn't exist.
In Lua you can do this with metatables and the `__index & __newindex` methods.

```
--Lua code
o = setmetatable({},{__index=function(self,key)
  print("tried to undefined key",key)
  return nil
end
})
```

So I'm wondering if there is something similar in javascript.

What I'm trying to achieve is a generic RPC interface that works like this (not valid Javascript):

```
function RPC(url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

RPC.prototype.__index=function(methodname) //imagine that prototype.__index exists
{ 
    AJAX.get(this.url+"?call="+ methodname);
}

var proxy = RPC("http://example.com/rpcinterface");
proxy.ServerMethodA(1,2,3);
proxy.ServerMethodB("abc");
```

So how can I do this?

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: this answer is no longer correct. ECMAScript 2015 ([ECMA-262 6th Ed.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) §§ 9.5, 26.2) defined [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects, which can be used to achieve this.

In JavaScript engines that don't provide `Proxy`, this functionality is still unavailable. In those engines, idioms which in Lua would rely on `__index` and `__newindex` will have to be expressed in some other way, like below.

---

javascript is more like scheme than it is like smalltalk (which supports method not defined) or lua.  Unfortunately your request is not supported to the best of my knowledge.

You could emulate this behaviour with an extra step.

```
function CAD(object, methodName) // Check and Attach Default
{
    if (!(object[methodName] && typeof object[methodName] == "function") &&
         (object["__index"] && typeof object["__index"] == "function")) {
        object[methodName] = function() { return object.__index(methodName); };
    }
}
```

so your example becomes

```
function RPC(url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

RPC.prototype.__index=function(methodname) //imagine that prototype.__index exists
{ 
    AJAX.get(this.url+"?call="+ methodname);
}

var proxy = RPC("http://example.com/rpcinterface");
CAD(proxy, "ServerMethodA");
proxy.ServerMethodA(1,2,3);
CAD(proxy, "ServerMethodB");
proxy.ServerMethodB("abc");
```

more functionality could be implemented in CAD but this gives you the idea...you could even use it as a calling mechanism that calls the function with arguments if it exists, bypassing the extra step I introduced.

Comment: I kinda imagined that javascript had an __index, and that i just couldn't find it, but seems I was wrong. Thanks for information and trick. It's good enough for my purposes!

Answer (score 5):

> asked 8 years, 8 months ago

Now we can use 'Proxy'

[Proxy - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

A simple way to use :

--Lua code

```
local o = setmetatable({},{__index=function(self,key)
  print("tried to undefined key",key)
  return nil
end
```

//With Proxy in Javascript

```
let o = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function (target, key, receiver) {
        if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            console.log("tried to undefined key "+key);
        }
        return Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
    },
    set: function (target, key, value, receiver) {
        console.log(`set `+ key);
        return Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
    }
})
```

get : __index

set : __newindex

Reflect.get : rawget

Reflect.set : rawset

in console:

```
let o= new Proxy({},{
    get: function (target, key, receiver) {
            let ret = Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
            if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                console.log("tried to undefined key "+key);
            }
            return ret;
        }
})
>> undefined

o.a
>> VM383:5 tried to undefined key a
>> undefined

o.a = 1
>> 1

o.a
>> 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI: Firefox supports a non-standard [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) extension.

Comment: thanks for the info, unfortunately I need cross-browser compatability, but nice to know, maybe others will follow suite

Answer (score 0):

I assume your actual need is more complicated than the example, because you're doing nothing with the parameters you're passing to `ServerMethodA` and `ServerMethodB`, and otherwise you would just do something like

```
function RPC(url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

RPC.prototype.callServerMethod = function(methodname, params)
{ 
    AJAX.get(this.url+"?call="+ methodname);
}

var proxy = RPC("http://example.com/rpcinterface");
proxy.callServerMethod("ServerMethodA", [1,2,3]);
proxy.callServerMethod("ServerMethodB", "abc");
```